# What are some uses of oxidative/reductive power inside cells?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, organic-chemistry

I know respiration and photosynthesis are based on oxidation and reduction, and the formation of NADH and NADPH in them is very important for many cell processes. I know that NADPH, for example, is used in the CBB cycle to fix carbon. However where else are oxidation and reduction reactions needed in cells? I can think of an example for oxidation: getting rid of toxic products. For example, alcohol dehydrogenase in the liver oxidises alcohol to acetaldehyde. However I can't think of much else, and i'm especially stuck on ehy reductive power is useful in cells.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is quite broad, excluding energetic metabolism, there are still **many** reactions that use redox equivalents, whether NADH, NADPH, or FADH. Here are some paradigmatic illustrations.

### Xenobiotic metabolism

- **Oxydation of substrate** : as you mentioned, alcohol to aldehyde to carboxylic acid. Generate reducing power. (The alkane oxydation shown below occurs in bacteria)

[image: Alkane oxydation]

- **Mono-oxygenation** : hydroxylation of a substrate with $O_2$, with the other oxygen atom reduced to water. This proceeds as follow with CYP450 enzymes :

[image: Monooxygenation using CYP450]

- **Regeneration of oxided gluthatione**
  [image: GTH regeneration]

### Anabolic metabolism

Basically every time there is a need to create/remove a double bond, or move from carbonyl to aldehyde to alcohol and back, redox equivalent are used.

- **Fatty acid elongation** : as this proceeds with acetyl-CoA as carbon source, intuitively one sees the need to reduce the carbonyl to obtain an alkane chain.

[image: Fatty acid synthesis]

- **HMG-CoA Reductase** (HMGCoAR) catalyses the commited step in cholesterol synthesis.

[image]

- **Synthesis of prostaglandins** from arachidonic acid. (More generally, any lipidic mediator)

[image: prostacyclin synthesis]

There are many, many more examples. You may want to check out the Wikipedia page for [NADH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide), [NADPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide_phosphate), [FADH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavin_adenine_dinucleotide), or the list of enzyme that use them ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:NADH-dependent_enzymes), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:NADPH-dependent_enzymes), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAD_dependent_oxidoreductase_family))

All illustrations from **Biochemical Pathways**, G. Michal & D. Schomburg, 2nd edition, Wiley